# Problem with Rudin's proof that $\operatorname{diam}\mkern2mu\overline{\mkern-2muE}=\operatorname{diam}\text{ }E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Here is a picture of Rudin's proof:

[image]

It's the red outlined part that I'm having problems with, because it seems to me that unless both $p$ and $q$ are limit points, points $p'$ and $q'$ might not exist.

Comment: If $p$ isn't a limit point of $E$, then $p \in E$ and we can just take $p'=p$

Comment: If $p$ is not a limit point, then $p \in E$ so choose $p'=p.$

Comment: The selection of $p'$ and $q'$ is uninteresting if you already have $p,q\in E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? *By definition* of closure, asserting that $p\in\overline E$ means that $p\in E$ or that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. In both cases, it is true that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $p\in E$ such that $d(p,p')<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities are that either $p$ or $q$ or both are in $E$ anyway. If they are not they are in $\bar E$ but not in $E$ and they are limit points of $E$.